# does $\sqrt[i]{x}$ have infinite solutions like the complex logarithm?

Tags: complex-numbers

We know that $\log(x)= z+ 2πix$ where $z$ is a solution to $\log(x)$ and for any integer $x$.

Can a similar derivation be made for $\sqrt[i]{x}$? Intuition says yes because of a derivation of Euler's identity is 
$$e^x= \sqrt[i]{\cos(x)+ i\sin(x)}$$

For example, according to the python programming language, $\sqrt[i]{\cos(7)+i\sin(7)}$ $\approx$ $2.04789962$ but does not equal $e^7$.

So obviously multiple solutions exist for $\sqrt[i]{x}$.

My question is, given a solution to  $\sqrt[i]{x}$, how can another solution be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $z=e^{i \theta}=e^{i \theta+i2\pi k}$. We would have:

$$z^\frac 1 i=(e^{i \theta+i2\pi k})^{\frac 1i}=e^{ \theta+2\pi k}$$

Infinitely many solutions

Comment: So given a solution, adding 2$\pi*x$ for integer x would yield another solution?

Comment: Well, you need to add it to the exponent

Comment: Ok, so given a solution $x$, $x+ e^{2\pi k}$ would yield another solution?

Comment: No. It would be more complicated if the number is not $e^{i\theta}$ I simply demonstrated that there would be multiple solutions